# Android facebook SDK post to walll

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to post a message to my wall on facebook using Android SDK. I once tried this before and it succeeded. It posted a rectangular frame with a icon on the left hand corner a caption and a message. This is my code.

```
final  Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                        parameters.putString("to", friendId);
                        parameters.putString("caption", "Little Cast Invitation");
                        parameters.putString("description", "Please View my video");
                        parameters.putString("message","Hello"); 
                        parameters.putString("icon", "http://www.veryicon.com/icon/png/Object/Points%20Of%20Interest/Theater%20Yellow%202.png");
                        parameters.putString("name","Invitation to View Video");
                        Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", parameters,"POST", new myPostListener(), 1);
```

This only post a message "Hello" onto my wall. everything else is ignored ? Any help in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

private Facebook facebook;

```
public void postMessageOnWall(Activity activity, String message, String picture, String caption, String name) {
    if (facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("message", message);
        parameters.putString("picture", picture);
        parameters.putString("caption", caption);
        parameters.putString("name", name);
        try {
            String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
            System.out.println(response);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```